# Convert Jquery Select Menu to Hamburger (TBS)

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

My theme, a child of Cherry Framework, included a jquery mobile menu @media 767px that is ugly.

You can see it in action right now on [my website.](http://herbalnitro.com)

I want to convert it into a hamburger (3 horizontal lines in span) collapse, but haven't quite figured out how to do that as my knowledge of php and jquery is nonexistent, and my html/css rather low.

The php is calling the nav in the static/static-nav, and I intuit I can just add bootstrap html and navbar-collapse related classes in the "nav class=" below to make it work.

```
<?php /* Static Name: Navigation */ ?>
<!-- BEGIN MAIN NAVIGATION -->
<nav class="nav nav__primary clearfix">
<?php if (has_nav_menu('header_menu')) {
    wp_nav_menu( array(
        'container'      => 'ul',
        'menu_class'     => 'sf-menu',
        'menu_id'        => 'topnav',
        'depth'          => 0,
        'theme_location' => 'header_menu',
        'walker'         => new description_walker()
    ));
} else {
    echo '<ul class="sf-menu">';
        $ex_page = get_page_by_title( 'Privacy Policy' );
        if ($ex_page === NULL) {
            $ex_page_id = '';
        } else {
            $ex_page_id = $ex_page->ID;
        }
        wp_list_pages( array(
            'depth'    => 0,
            'title_li' => '',
            'exclude'  => $ex_page_id
            )
        );
    echo '</ul>';
} ?>
</nav><!-- END MAIN NAVIGATION -->
```

The parent framework is making sf-menu display none @ 767px. I'd like to just override that in the child css with bootstrap stuffs.

**Any** help would be so appreciated.

Sincerely,
Jordan

Comment: So you're asking two questions: override the `display: none` @ 767px and style the jQuery mobile menu?

Comment: Hi Chris. Essential I want to replace the jQuery mobile menu with a hamburger menu. I figured the easiest way to do that would be to either replace the plugin with a hamburger plugin, or remove the plugin and collapse the nav with only bootstrap css classes.

Comment: here is an example of "hamburger": https://stackoverflow.com/a/43281947/4845566